# Trouble with creating new folders/directories

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program that crawls a folder for a specific data type, creates a new folder inside that folder, and makes a copy of each file of that data type inside.

I've gotten it to work by making a copy of the files in a different folder that already exists, but I'd like to do it all in one go. This is the code so far:

```
import glob, os, shutil

def imageSearch(folder):
    newFolder = folder + '\\imgCopy'
    if not os.path.isdir(newFolder):
        os.makedirs(newFolder)
    files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(folder, '*.jpg'))
    for file in files:
        if os.path.isfile(file):
            shutil.copy2(file, newFolder)

print('Which folder are you crawling?')
imageSearch(input())
```

No error messages so far, just not getting any new folder or files.

Comment: maybe you need `os.walk(folder)` to get all folders and subfolders in original location.

Comment: Consider altering `folder + '\\imgCopy'` to `os.path.join(folder,'imgCopy')`. Using this method is not compulsary and if you are working at one OS slashes\backslashes works, but code looks somewhat inconsisent if you use both slashes\backslashes in paths and `os.path.join`

Comment: @Daweo completely agree, used that in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. Since you're new here, and this is an easy problem, here's a full solution.

```py
import glob, os, shutil

def imageSearch(folder, ext='jpg'):
    if os.path.isdir(folder):
        newFolder = os.path.join(folder, folder+'Copy')
        print(newFolder)
        if not os.path.isdir(newFolder):
            os.makedirs(newFolder)
        for file in glob.iglob(os.path.join(folder, '*.'+ext)):
            if os.path.isfile(file):
                shutil.copy2(file, newFolder)
    else:
        print("Folder does not exist.")

folder = input('Which folder are you crawling?\n')
ext = input('What file extension would you like to search for?\n')
imageSearch(folder, ext)
```

I'll now explain what I did. First of all (the thing that fixed your code), I replaced `newFolder = folder + '\\imgCopy'` with `newFolder = os.path.join(folder, folder+'Copy')` because `os.path.join()` will fix any issues automatically for you (does folder end in a trailing slash? Is the user using a filesystem where directories separated by forward or backward slashes?). I used `folder+'Copy'` in case the folder isn't named `img`. I also removed the extraneous variable `files` because it is used once. I added an `os.path.isdir()` at the start to protect against non-existent folders. Lastly, I allowed customization of the extension with the optional argument `ext`.

Outside of the function, I removed the extraneous `print` statement: `input` can print a prompt by default.

Comment: This fixes a lot of the basic mistakes I've been making. Thank you!